# Cannot find Aela on second werewolf totem

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

I am on the second totem and have successfully retrieved it, but Aelia went missing and I don't know where she went. I looked for her everywhere - all the houses she might be in. When I try to get other companions it says I've got one. I've even done other quests hoping she would appear but she didn't.

Where can I find her? I really don't want to start over again.

Comment: I lost Aelia for a long time too. She reappeared after the liberation of the town where the companions reside.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on PC you could try console commands. Load a previous save with Aela, open console(`) and then click on her to find out her id. Copy down the her id. Load back you latest game and use following commands:

- prid "Aela's id" (without the the quotes, "")
- moveto player

That should move Aela to your current location. (You can also probably find her id on the wiki)

If you cannot use another companion, try hiring a mercenary and then going back to a different companion. (Though I am not sure how effective this is)

Apart from that you can try waiting for sometime or fast travelling.

Comment: also always remember to save your game before using console commands.

Comment: thx im on the PS3 and lost her but i will try the mercenary thing my fear is she may have glitched thru the map so imma use shadowmere to see if i can glitch to see her i willl let  kno how the merc trick works out tho thx

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, and decided that I would go to Jorrvaskr in Whiterun. I went to bed, slept for a day and bam: she appeared.